# How to prevent attaching the event to newly creating elements in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

If I hover on the appended text then also it is showing the tooltip. How can I prevent this so it shouldn't fire for newly created elements?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').append("<b>Appended text</b>");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tooltip Example</h3>
  <div data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: dont put the appended text inside the div with tool hover event

Comment: You're appending the text within the element with the event handler. If you don't want to fire the event on the new content, don't put it inside that element

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i am using select library they are appending into my element so i can't change that library :(

Comment: @guradio can i remove tooltip from particular child element ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can i remove that tooltip from newly created element using jquery off  ?

Comment: you can assign the tool hover to specific element if you can change the mark up

Comment: @Mahi in your mark up the div have the hover event and the things you append is inside that div if you dont want you can wrap the text then have the tool tip on that wrapper

Comment: @guradio select library is appending into my parent element . i can't change that behavior :( can it work using jquery off for newly created element ?

Answer (score 0):

`append()` means that you're inserting newly created element inside the parent which is have the tooltip. So of course the tooltip appearing because you place the new element inside.

If you want to place the new element outside the element which have the tooltip (so they will not have the tooltip), then use `after()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').after("<b>Appended text</b>");
});
```

## UPDATE

Seems I know your problem now. If you must append it and don't want tooltip to that element only, it's generally impossible. The solution is you should embed the bootstrap tooltip to the specific child, not on the parent. Like this:

```
<div><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</span></div>
```

Then you can append the `<p>` element to the `<div>`. That's it. Good luck!

Comment: sorry but that's a example i have given .. i am using library that is appending into my element so i can't change that library :(

Comment: then you must try embed the bootstrap tooltip in correct (specific) elements, not on the parent.

Comment: can i remove that tooltip from newly created element using jquery off ?

Comment: you can't, because the tooltip is not on that new element but on it's parent which you append them in ... or maybe you want to try using css `pointer-events: none;` for the new element, but I don't know that will work out or no.